# Earn reputation, example rep count is wrong

Tags: bug, status-planned, documentation, design

In the [Documentation page](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation), when click on the **Earn Reputation** section, there is some content about the reputation is displaying.

There for the **Example upvoted**, the description is as

> All contributors receive +5 rep.

but in the image above, it shows +10 rep.

In the remaining places, the rep and the description is matching.

[image]

**Update:**

There is new design change in the Documentation page, but still the issue is exists.

[image: In new design]

Comment: They also need to update the text as not all contributors get the full rep on a upvote anymore.

Comment: Yeah, we need to update these for sure. Thanks for the report!