# Picture in banner does not match rep amount

Tags: bug, documentation

In [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation) there is a banner that runs through a quick tour.  When you get to the earn reputation page part you see

[image: earn reputation banner]

And if we look at the example upvoted part the icon shows 10 rep but the text says 5 rep

[image: image showing more clearly the 10 vs 5 rep]

Can we get these to match?

Comment: [Your memory appears to be slipping](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344275/earn-reputation-example-rep-count-is-wrong#comment450098_344275) ;-)

Comment: @CodyGray It is.  Only 5 month ago and I can't remember :(